# store state of dynamic component in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have a react component RegisterWindow.js which dynamically child elements Category.js. Register window has progress bar ProgressBar.js with 3 steps. When you click on the previous step Category.js looses its state. What is the best way to maintain state in such case. Code is as follows :

### Step1 (Tickets)

[image]

### Step 2 (Attendees)

[image]

You can see in the Tickets image that I have selected 2 tickets. When I go back from Attendee screen to Tickets using progress bar links, I loose the state and no of tickets becomes 0. Each ticket row is separate reactjs component and created dynamically.

Comment: can you post a code instead of images?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common pattern which emerges when we have parent-child relationship ( uni-directional data flow ) between components. Read this for more - [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

You can just lift the state ( which stores your tickets ) to the parent component ( probably where the stepper is implemented ). Then you can pass the same data to each sub-views on step change.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something along these lines :

> RegisterWindow.js

```
class RegisterWindow extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        ticketQty : 0,
        attendees : [],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <ProgressBar />
            <Tickets updateTickets={this.updateTickets} />
            <Attendees  ticketQty={this.state.ticketQty} addAttendees={this.addAttendees} />
            <Confirmation />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> Tickets.js

```
class Tickets extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         //All the UI elements
        <button onClick={this.props.updateTickets}> Add Ticket</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Essentially, you will define the `updateTickets` and `addAttendees` functions in the `RegisterWindow` file.

These will be passed as props to the individual components. These components will access the props and accordingly update the data.

TLDR : Data and Functions will flow from the `RegisterWindow` Component to the individual ones.